# Contract send ether from one address to many another address by one click

Tags: contract-development

I need to know how to send ether from one address to many another address by one click. Please help me. if you now link video, it is very usefull. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use a splitter. It is a smart contract that send ether to multiple address in one transaction.

There are many so I advise you to do your own research. Here is one I know : https://app.0xsplits.xyz/